# Kubeflow manifest installation receiving runtime error: slice bounds out of range [20:0] while adding contributors Via Manage Contributors in UI

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Kubeflow version: 1.6.1
GKE cluster: 1.23

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hybUV.png)I should be successful in adding contributors in UI

```
Error in ProfileDeployment and Error in centralDashboard
```

```
http: panic serving 10.20.20.20:55448: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [20:0]
goroutine 207 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1802 +0x13a
panic({0x1791a40, 0xc0003966a8})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x262
github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/components/access-management/kfam.(*KfamV1Alpha1Client).getUserEmail(0xc0001143c0, 0xc00031b380)
    /workspace/kfam/api_default.go:290 +0xac
github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/components/access-management/kfam.(*KfamV1Alpha1Client).CreateBinding(0xc0001143c0, {0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6900)
    /workspace/kfam/api_default.go:116 +0x268
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000116720, {0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6900)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2047 +0x43
github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/components/access-management/kfam.Logger.func1({0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6900)
    /workspace/kfam/logger.go:23 +0xb2
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00012f3b0, {0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6900)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2047 +0x43
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0003e3a40, {0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6900)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.2/mux.go:212 +0x26f
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc0003d6000}, {0x193d8d8, 0xc0003ee1c0}, 0xc0003e6700)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2879 +0x47a
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00040c140, {0x19417f0, 0xc000390300})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1930 +0x18b8
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
```

```
Unable to add new contributor for user-: Error: socket hang up
```